# React/Redux, Reloading a component in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the typical list of rows in a basic CRUD screen, each row, as usual with the link:

```
<Link to={"/appointment/"+appointment.id+"/"}>Edit</Link>
```

My route is:

```
<Route path="/appointment/:id" component={AppoModal} />
```

when I click "Edit" in any row a Modal dialogue appears:

[image]

If I do click in the first "Edit" link all works fine. But if I push the "Close" button in the dialogue and try to click any "Edit" link again, the modal dialogue is not launched, I guess this is happening because the component is already "up".

The hide/show behaviour of the dialogue is controlled by **this.state.showModal** value in the AppoModal component:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showModal: true };
 }
```

So I don't know how to "reload" or "re run" the component. Can I run a dispatch(action) every time I click in the "Edit" link? I heard about a "static method", but I'm too newbie with React to know if that is the path.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because when you click Close, you're changing the component state, but you're not changing the application state.

Since your modal opens with a route change, it should also close with a route change.

Comment: Man, you are good, 

    <Button onClick={() =>    browserHistory.push('/appointments')}>Close</Button>

made the trick. Thx David!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different approach and avoid the route change all together. Since you are using redux, you could have a global state which could contain a modal name as a constant or maybe contain the reference to the Component.

Now you can have a modal component that would render the component depending on the global state change and you can call this component somewhere in the root Component.

so your reducer looks like

```
export function modalState(state=null, action) {
  if(action.payload.name == "CLOSE_MODAL") return null;
  else if([/*modal names*/].includes(action.payload.name) {
    return {modal: action.payload.name, .data: action.payload.data}
  } else return {...state}
}
```

and you have an action like

```
export function openModal(name, data) {
  return {
    type: "MODAL_NAME",
    payload: { name, data }
}

export function closeModal() {
  return { type: "CLOSE_MODAL", payoad: null }
}
```

and your component could look like

```
const componentMaps = {
  [MODAL_1] : import MODAL_1 from "./modals/Modal_1.jsx"
}
cont Modal = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    let Component = componentMaps[this.props.modal.name]
    if(Component) {
      return <Component {...this.props.modal.data}/>
    } else { 
      return null;
    }
  }
});

export connect(select)(Modal);
```